# CSS table cell inputs not taking full width

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have a snippet in my project that involves laying out a grid for a form using CSS tables. However, I am having trouble making it work where it does not take up the full width as I would expect.

```css
.full_width {
  width: 100%
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table_row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table_cell {
  display: table-cell
}
.wrapper_cont {
  width: 48%
}
#cell2 {
  padding-left: 4%
}
.label {
  display: block
}
.margin_bottom {
  margin-bottom: 18px
}
```

```html
<div class="table full_width">
  <div class="table_cell full_width">
    <div id="does_something_important">
      <div id="does_something_important2">
        <form class="table full_width" method="post">
          <div class="table_row full_width">
            <div class="margin_bottom">
              <div id="cell1" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                <span class="label">Name</span>
                <input class="full_width" value="Michael" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div id="cell2" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                <span class="label">Email</span>
                <input class="full_width" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="margin_bottom">
              <div id="cell1" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                <span class="label">Name</span>
                <input class="full_width" value="Michael" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div id="cell2" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                <span class="label">Email</span>
                <input class="full_width" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/kq70cghc/7/

Comment: Any reason why you are using divs with table properties rather than tables themselves?

Comment: Easier for me to style them. Also personal preference if that matters.

Comment: try full_width 100% !important;

Comment: @Alex That most certainly would not work...and it's not valid CSS either,

Comment: @MindyChang you can always use margin property margin-left:0px and margin-right:0px

Comment: You have an inconsistency between the names you are using for the table_row css rule. You are using 'table_row' in the html and 'row' in your css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/kq70cghc/4/

Comment: also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4581077/4810628

Comment: did you try _inherit_?

Comment: Inherit width? I shouldn't have too. The code should work as expected in theory.

Comment: You have a surplus div between the table row div and the table cell divs. Try removing that: https://jsfiddle.net/1bemsj2h/

Comment: @rbgige Let me update the question. That div needs to be there to space more rows under it.

Comment: You need the immediacy between the table row and cell i.e. the cell needs to be a direct child of the row

Comment: "it does not take up the full width" - *what* doesn't take up the full width of *what*? The inputs are as wide as the table-cell-styled divs, so I'm having a hard time understanding what's actually going wrong here.

Comment: I'm trying to get the inputs to go right up to the edge of the table.

Comment: To keep the immediacy between the row and cell, add padding to your table cells instead of a margin to an intervening div: https://jsfiddle.net/9ymk03o4/

Comment: @rbginge This will work. Thanks :) You can add it in as an answer here and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the intervening margin_bottom div as it breaks the relationship between table-row and table-cell. And as you can't add margin to a table-row, to add spacing between rows, add the padding to the cells instead:

```css
.full_width{width: 100%}
.table{ display: table;}
.table_row{display: table-row;}
.table_cell{display:table-cell;padding-bottom: 18px;}
.wrapper_cont{width: 48%}
#cell2{padding-left: 4%}
.label{display:block}
```

```html
<div class="table full_width">
    <div class="table_cell full_width">
        <div id="does_something_important">
            <div id="does_something_important2">
                <form class="table full_width" method="post">
                    <div class="table_row full_width">
                            <div id="cell1" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                                <span class="label">Name</span>
                                <input class="full_width" value="Michael" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cell2" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                                <span class="label">Email</span>
                                <input class="full_width" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="table_row full_width">
                            <div id="cell1" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                                <span class="label">Name</span>
                                <input class="full_width" value="Michael" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                            <div id="cell2" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                                <span class="label">Email</span>
                                <input class="full_width" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra < div> tag that you are using.

```
<div class="table full_width">
<div class="table_cell full_width">
    <div id="does_something_important">
        <div id="does_something_important2">
            <form class="table full_width" method="post">
                <div class="table_row full_width">
                        <div id="cell1" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                            <span class="label">Name</span>
                            <input class="full_width" value="Michael" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="cell2" class="table_cell wrapper_cont">
                            <span class="label">Email</span>
                            <input class="full_width" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this should work!

Comment: I've updated the question. I actually need that div to add margin bottom. Unless there is a way I can ave the margin without having that div. I couldn't get border collapse to work and add it correctly to the table_row;